# rails, yml, & multiline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, newline, yaml, multiline

i cannot for the life of me get multiline yaml from my locale files to work.

i have tried every combination of multiple solutions with no success.

i have tried `key: |`, `key: >`, with double quotes, with singles quotes, with \n, with the value on the next line, indented, and probably some others.

and in my view i am just using `t('key')`

im tearing my hair out over here. any other suggestions or possible reasons the default yaml specs for multiline values are not working?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From some fooling around in irb, it looks like you might want:

```
key: |-
  abc
  def
```

Comment: hmm... not having any luck with that either.  is that something from the yaml specs?

Comment: No, I just entered a hash with a multiline value and called 'to_yaml' on it. Given your using rails, are you converting newlines to <br> before rendering?

Comment: ah geez. that was it.  simple_format was all i needed in the view.  i didnt even need to_yaml or declaring a hash for my value.  just the | and simple_format.  phew... thanks!