# How to insert line feeds in locale file? 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to insert line feeds in locale file(en.yml) in Ruby on Rails?

I want to display a string, that is defined in the locale file (`en.yml`) with a line feed.

I defined the locale file(en.yml) like below:

```
en:
  testmsg: |
   this is line1.
   this is line2.
```

And I created view file(~.html.erb) like below:

```
<h1><%= t :testmsg %></h1>
```

But the result was like below:

```
this is line1.this is line2.
```

There is no line feed in the result.

How to insert line feeds in locale file (`en.yml`) in Ruby on Rails?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151526/rails-yml-multiline

Comment: Nobita,
Thank you very much for your advice.
I solved my problem.
"simple_format" method is needed in view.

Answer (score 0):

At `en.yml` you have plain text, but the view is html. You have an `\n` instead a `<br />`, so the text is rendered in the same line (thanks to how html processes blanks).

If you render that as plain text you will see two lines, but in this case some html markup is needed.

You can put some html in the `en.yml`, for example, or use more than one key (depending on your use cases)

Hope this helps.